# JDBCAppender tableName from Main Arguments Lookup

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

There is a JDBCAppender in my application to which I'd like to set the **tableName** parameter from a [main argument lookup](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#AppMainArgsLookup). Reason for this is that my database table may optionally have a prefix, so I'm reading this from a configuration file in my application and I'd like to apply it to the appender at runtime.

```
    <JDBC name="TaskLogJDBC" tableName="${main:1}LogEvents">
        <ConnectionFactory class="my.package.name.ConnectionFactory" method="getConnection"/>
        <Column name="created_on" isEventTimestamp="true"/>
        <Column name="lvl" pattern="%level"/>
        <Column name="logger" pattern="%logger"/>
        <Column name="message" pattern="%message"/>
        <Column name="throwable" pattern="%ex{full}"/>
    </JDBC>
```

This is what I use in **Main.java** to se the arguments:

```
MainMapLookup.setMainArguments(new String[] { "--prefix", tablesPrefix });
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. The JDBCAppender keeps reading the **tableName** parameter verbatim as *${main:0}LogEvents* instead of *prefix_LogEvents*. I traced it and I think the JDBCAppender configuration read happens before the *MainMapLookup.setMainArguments()* gets called. Is this a bug?

Environment variable lookup is an option, but I'd like to avoid it at this point. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** After some more trial and error, I found out that the issue comes from having declared a `Logger` in the `Main` class itself.

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
```

This loads the log4j2.xml including all JDBC appender parameters before `MainMapLookup.setMainArguments()` gets invoked. Removing the `logger` from above allows for the main arguments to get set.

---

Nothing that I tried worked, because it seems my log4j2.xml file gets loaded before my application's `main()` gets called. So, I ended up *hacking* the log4j2 `JdbcDatabaseManager` class by using reflection. This replaces the name of the table directly in the SQL statement.

```
    final var jdbcAppender = (JdbcAppender) loggerContext.getConfiguration().getAppender("AppenderName");
    final var jdbcManager = jdbcAppender.getManager();
    var field = jdbcManager.getClass().getDeclaredField("sqlStatement");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    String value = (String) field.get(jdbcManager);
    value = value.replace("__DUMMY_TABLE__", prefix + "TaskLog");
    field.set(jdbcManager, value);
```

The table name is defined as so in the log4j2.xml file:

```
    <JDBC name="AppenderName" tableName="__DUMMY_TABLE__">
```

It seems to have worked. Hope it's helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
static{
    MainMapLookup.setMainArguments(new String[] { "--prefix", tablesPrefix });
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code or expound on why this is the solution to the question.

Comment: Although a clever idea, this won't help. **tablesPrefix** gets loaded from an external file after the application starts. Additionally, it seems the appender config in **log4j2.xml** file is being read even before the **main()** method runs. This really ties my hands, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.13.0, you MUST call Log4j's `MainMapLookup.setMainArguments()` from your app's `main()` method or anywhere that array is available from your app.